# Determine total number of ways of reaching a destination

Tags: java, optimization, complexity

> **Question**:
>
> One of Scotland Yard’s most wanted criminal (Mister X) is on the run
>   and needs to reach a certain destination safely. There are three modes
>   of transport available for him - By air, by train or by cab.  With air
>   travel, he can go from station i to station i+3. Using a train would
>   make him reach station i+2 when starting from i and by taxi he could
>   go to the next station (i+1).
>
> Now, clearly there can be multiple ways of travelling between two
>   stations. Thus, you need to help him find out the total number of ways
>   of reaching station N from station 0. Since the number of ways can be
>   very large output the answer mod 10<sup>9</sup> +7.
>
> ***Input Specification***:
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases, T. This is followed
>   by T lines each containing an integer N, the station ID.
>
> ***Output Specification***:
>
> Print T lines, each line having the corresponding test case's output.
>
> **Sample Input**:
>
> 2 3 4
>
> **Sample Output**:
>
> 4 7
>
> **Constraints**:
>
> 1 <= T <= 100000
>
> 2 <= N <= 10<sup>7</sup>

**My code to be optimized:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        int testCases=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        short ways[]=new short[testCases],i=0;
        int stationId;
        while(testCases!=0)
        {
            stationId = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            ways[i++] = (short)(getWays(stationId)%(10^9 +7));
            testCases--;
        }   
        for(int k:ways)
            System.out.println(k);
    }
    static int getWays(int n)
    {
        int sum = 1,i=1;
        while(i<=n)
        {
            sum+=(i-1);
            i++;
        }
        return sum;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You should only change an edit for improvement of formatting only if any meaning in your question was lost.  In this case, there wasn't any information lost, so I rolled back the edit.

Comment: Your sample input does not adhere to the input specification?

Comment: Clarification: In the description it says: *Since the number of ways can be very large output the answer mod xxxx*. Is the `xxxx` *10-to-the-power-of-9-plus-7*, or is it *10-xor-9-plus-7* ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java

Comment: Please do not change the code in the question after it has been answered, as it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 9):

Although this is not related to optimization, it looks like you could improve some of the ways you use loops.  If you're using a counter, chances are you should use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) { /*...*/ }
```

This works best if the loop counter initialization is pretty short.  But if it's too long and should remain on its own line, then instead have a `while` loop that updates the counter within the statement:

```
int i; // some long initialization here instead...

while (i-- > 0) { /*...*/ }
```

First, I want to mention that you should use whitespace between operators and keywords for readability.  You use it in some places, but you should use it everywhere for consistency.

Second, non-empty code blocks should have the opening curly brace at the end of the line, not on the following line.  This is referenced in [Google Java Style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.1.2-blocks-k-r-style).

Instead of decrementing `testCases` within the loop:

```
while(testCases!=0)
{
    stationId = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    ways[i++] = (short)(getWays(stationId)%(10^9 +7));
    testCases--;
}
```

have it done in the `while` loop statement:

```
while (testCases-- > 0) {
    stationId = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    ways[i++] = (short)(getWays(stationId)%(10^9 +7));
}
```

Instead of incrementing `i` within the loop:

```
while(i<=n)
{
    sum+=(i-1);
    i++;
}
```

make it a `for` loop:

```
// move the initialization of i into the loop

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += (i-1);
}
```

On another note, this:

```
short ways[]=new short[testCases],i=0;
```

should be on separate lines:

```
short ways[] = new short[testCases];
short i = 0;
```

Although they're of the same type, `i` is hard to see since it's crammed right next to `ways[]`.